# Why my head->node is NULL but my linked list is full of data and sometimes foor loop works and sometimes not in linked list. AMONG_US GAME

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So

1. i have a doubly linked list Players that i store stuct Players
2. i have a linked list in accending order that i store struct Tasks

and i want to put that tasks in every players that is not alien(players->is_alien != 1) so in the end i will have a linked list with lists.

STRUCTS:

```
struct Players{

    int pid;                     
    int is_alien;                 
    int evidence;                
    struct Players *prev;         
    struct Players *next;         
    struct Tasks *tasks_head;     
    struct Tasks *tasks_sentinel; 
};

struct Tasks{

    int tid;                     
    int difficulty;             
    struct Tasks *next;            
};

struct Head_GL{

    int tasks_count[3];           
    struct Tasks *head;           
};
```

GLOBAL VARIABLES:

```
struct Players *players_head;

struct Head_GL *tasks_head;
```

I code the part that i store players in the doubly linked list all works fine and i have 2 problems.

1. Why the printf with the for loop is working fine but with while loop i have segmatation fault i think

THIS IS OKAY

```
int insert_task(int tid,int difficulty) {

    int num_task=0;
    struct Tasks *prev=NULL;
    struct Tasks *temp=NULL;
    struct Tasks *new=(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks));

    if(new==NULL)
        return 0;
    new->tid = tid;
    new->difficulty = difficulty;
    new->next = NULL;

    if(difficulty==1)
        tasks_head->tasks_count[0]+=1;
    else if(difficulty==2)
        tasks_head->tasks_count[1]++;
    else
        tasks_head->tasks_count[2]++;
    
    num_task=tasks_head->tasks_count[0]+tasks_head->tasks_count[1]+tasks_head->tasks_count[2];

    if(tasks_head->head==NULL){
        tasks_head->head = new;
    }
    else if( tasks_head->head->difficulty > difficulty){
        new->next = tasks_head->head;
        tasks_head->head= new;
    }
    else{
        prev = tasks_head->head;
        temp = tasks_head->head->next;
        while(temp != NULL && temp->difficulty < difficulty){
            prev = temp;
            //tasks_head->head=temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp==NULL){
            prev->next = new;
            new->next=NULL;
            //tasks_head->head->next=new;
        }
        else{
            new->next = temp;
            prev->next = new;
            //tasks_head->head->next=new;
        }
    }
    **struct Tasks *t=tasks_head->head;
    printf("Tasks= ");
    for(int i=0; i<num_task; i++){
        printf("< %d %d > ", t->tid,t->difficulty);
        printf(" ");
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("\n");**
    return 1;
}
```

BUT SAME CODE WITH WHILE PRINTF IS FAULT

```
printf("Tasks= ");
    
    while(t!=NULL){
        printf("< %d %d > ", t->tid,t->difficulty);
        printf(" ");
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}
```

2. If i use the foor loop in other function make segmatation fault and if i do this function with while loop the task_head->next ==NULL but the linked list with task is full of data 100%

```
int distribute_tasks() {

    struct Players *curr_p = players_head;
    struct Tasks *curr_t = tasks_head->head;
    int num=tasks_head->tasks_count[0]+tasks_head->tasks_count[1]+tasks_head->tasks_count[2];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        while(curr_p->is_alien == 1){
            curr_p=curr_p->next;
        }
        if(curr_p->tasks_head == NULL){
            curr_p->tasks_head=curr_t;
            curr_p->tasks_head->next=curr_p->tasks_sentinel;
            curr_p->tasks_sentinel=curr_p->tasks_head;
        }
        else{
           curr_p->tasks_head->next=curr_t;
           curr_p->tasks_sentinel->next=curr_t;
           curr_t->next=curr_p->tasks_sentinel;
        }
        curr_p=curr_p->next;
        curr_t=curr_t->next;
    }


int distribute_tasks() {
  
    
    struct Players *curr_p = players_head;
    struct Tasks *curr_t = tasks_head->head;
    int num=tasks_head->tasks_count[0]+tasks_head->tasks_count[1]+tasks_head->tasks_count[2];
    while(curr_t!=NULL){
        while(curr_p->is_alien == 1){
            curr_p=curr_p->next;
        }
        if(curr_p->tasks_head == NULL){
            curr_p->tasks_head=curr_t;
            curr_p->tasks_head->next=curr_p->tasks_sentinel;
            curr_p->tasks_sentinel=curr_p->tasks_head;
        }
        else{
           curr_p->tasks_head->next=curr_t;
           curr_p->tasks_sentinel->next=curr_t;
           curr_t->next=curr_p->tasks_sentinel;
        }
        curr_p=curr_p->next;
        curr_t=curr_t->next;
    }
```

if someone wants to help and needs more information just say it. Thanks you

Comment: where is your global variable `tasks_head` is getting set?

Comment: i have 3 files . Main.c , among_us.c and among_us.h . Is getting set ina mong_us.h and i develop the function in among_us.c

Comment: its better to narrow down the question to problem area using debug statements like `printf` or better yet `gdb`